# Generating and printing random multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, random

I want to generate multiple random lists and print them. How shall I append each list uniquely with every loop? The code below doesn't append the list that is being generated with the empty lists. It simply prints the empty lists.

```
import numpy as np
a,b,c,d,e=[],[],[],[],[]
for i in range(0,4):
    j=np.random.randint(0,15,size=7)
    [a,b,c,d,e].append(j)
print(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing random 1-D arrays in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62839999/printing-random-1-d-arrays-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> a,b,c,d,e=[],[],[],[],[]
> # ...
> [a,b,c,d,e].append(j)
> ```

This does *not* change `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.

It creates a new list containing `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, appends `j` to it, and then discards it.

To append `j` to each of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, use a `for` loop:

```
for lst in [a,b,c,d,e]:
    lst.append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a random sequence(list) containing numbers between 0 and 15.

```
import random

for _ in range(4):
    print(random.sample(range(16),15))
```

---

`random.sample(population, k)`

- Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
  sequence or set.
- Used for random sampling without replacement.
- If the population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a
  possible selection in the sample.