# Printing random 1-D arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

This code gives 2D arrays but I need multiple 1-dimensional arrays with random numbers.

```
a,b,c,d,e=[],[],[],[],[]
for i in (a,b,c,d,e):
     j=np.random.randint(0,15,size=7)
     i.append(j)
print(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? All it takes is a few `print()` statements, I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: This was helpful. Will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You append numpy array to a list, so you got 2D.
Try this

```py
import numpy as np

a, b, c, d, e = (np.random.randint(0,15,size=7) for i in range(5))
print(a,b,c,d,e)
```